# Action(() => { }) via the dispatcher freezes the ui

Tags: c#, async-await

I tried a simple async-await example with and without `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.
With `.ConfigureAwait(false)` you can update the ui via the dispatcher, which is unneccesary without it.
This is case 1 and 3 in the code below - that works and I can understand how it works.

My question is about case 2 where I add a - completely unneccesary -- refresh
`Action(() => { })` via the dispatcher.
This occasionally freezes my ui. Especially after invoking the eventhandler repeatedly.
Can anybody explain why the ui freezes in case 2?

```
private void Test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Test();
}

public async void Test()
{
    Print("Start task");

    // Case 1 & 2
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    // Case 3
    await Task.Delay(2000).ConfigureAwait(false);

    Print("Finished task");
}

void Print(string text)
{
    // Case 1 & 2
    Output.Inlines.Add(new Run(text) { Foreground = Brushes.Blue, FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
    // Case 2 only
    Output.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => { }));

    // Case 3
    Output.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, 
       new Action(() => 
       {  
         Output.Inlines.Add(new Run(text) { Foreground = Brushes.Blue, FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold 
       }); }));
}
```

Comment: Pause in the debugger and look at the stack trace.

Comment: It's not the `Action(() => {})` that is pausing your UI. It's the `Task.Delay(2000)` that does not have the `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Since it is configured to run on the UI thread, your UI thread will hang for 2 seconds at an unspecified time. That unspecified time turns out being the run of case 2.

Comment: @RaymondChen: the delay is awaited and doesn't freeze at all. Only after adding the empty action it does.

Comment: @SLaks When it is frozen I cannot pause the debugger. The call stack after returning from await starts with: resuming async action.

Comment: Huh? You should **always** be able to pause the debugger, unless Visual Studio itself is broken.  You may need to disable Just My Code to see the stack trace.

Comment: @RaymondChen: No; that's still an async call; it's just resuming on the UI thread.

Comment: `Dispatcher.Invoke` is a synchronous method. It will wait until the UI message queue is available to process your action. If that queue is busy processing other messages, your UI will freeze.

Comment: Do you run these "cases" separately each time? or do you invoke them all every click?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I just run case 2.

Comment: @SLaks: well in fact my whole laptop freezes and only via starting the task manager and closing it, visual studio becomes reactive again. That strangeness is the reason I ask.

Comment: Is any other piece of code executing in parallel to this?

Comment: How many cores do you have? Can you lower the priority of your app process in Task Manager so you can hit pause in VS? If you can use Task Manager, why can't you use VS too?

Comment: Also, what version of .Net? This may be a bug in the dispatcher.

Comment: Does this occur when running the process outside of `vshost`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Yes; I reproduced it.  It's hanging on `GetMessageW()`, which is weird.  This looks like a bug in WPF.

Comment: Yes i see that happen now.

Comment: Thanks for trying and reproducing. Relieved it isn't me.

Comment: @RaymondChen: My previous comment is totally wrong.  Any idea why `GetMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0)` would hang?

Comment: Similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127625/why-would-getmessagew-take-up-massive-cpu-usage-in-my-wpf-application

Comment: @Gerard: While this is interesting, for real-world code you should be using `IProgress<string>` rather than `Dispatcher`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in WPF.

<strike>It runs a filtered `GetMessage()` loop (see [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/src/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs#2278)), which [will hang](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/src/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs#2278) if the is a message stuck in the queue that doesn't meet the filter.</strike>

Comment: Looking further, my explanation is wrong; it isn't actually filtering anything.  It's still a bug in WPF, but I have no idea why it would hang.

Comment: @hvd: Yes; I just realized that.  Any idea why it would hang?

Comment: @SLaks I realised that you realised that when I saw your comment. :) No, no idea.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127625/why-would-getmessagew-take-up-massive-cpu-usage-in-my-wpf-application

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: But that doesn't explain why it's hanging.

Comment: I know. But declaring it as a bug is a bit grandiose